# TeXstudio previewer reverts to embedded?

Tags: texstudio

I would like the TeXstudio previewer to run "windowed", rather than "embedded".  The "Configure/Build" screen claims to give me my choice, and changing from "Internal PDF Viewer (Embedded)" to "Internal PDF Viewer (Windowed)" works properly for the rest of the current session of TeXstudio.  But, if I exit TeXstudio and restart it, then the previewer mode has mysteriously changed back to "embedded".

I am running TeXstudio version 2.10.2 under Windows 10.  This issue doesn't seem to be a problem, say, with write permission on the ".ini" file, since changes to other settings are correctly remembered across sessions.

Comment: Did you look at the `.ini` file?  Maybe you can change the setting by hand there.  Otherwise I guess that your question would be better suited for the [TeXstudio forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839) or [TeXstudio bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/).

Comment: Thanks, @jarahu, for the suggestion -- I have reposted to the TeXstudio bug tracker.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in TeXstudio 2.10.4.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating TeXstudio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bug was fixed in 2.10.4 as mentioned in comments.